# Zend_Form HTML/XHTML bug?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

There seems to be a little bug in Zenf_Form, as it uses

```
<br />
```

even for HTML doctype in a specific case.

This is how you can reproduce the error:

Create a form like this:

```
<?php
class Settings extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttrib('class', 'settings-form');

        $video_quality = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('video_quality', array(
            'label' => 'Video quality',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'input-radio',
            'multiOptions' => array(
                '1' => 'High (Minimum download bandwidth is 2 Mb/s)',
                '2' => 'Low (Minimum download bandwidth is 0.5 Mb/s)',
            )
        ));

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('save_settings', array(
            'label' => 'Uložiť',
            'class' => 'input-submit'
        ));

        $this->addElements(array(
            $video_quality,
            $submit
        ));
    }
}
```

Set your doctype to:

```
$view->doctype('HTML4_STRICT');
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',
                                   'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

And echo the form. This will be the output:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" class="settings-form" action="/clientarea/index/settings"><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="video_quality-label"><label class="required">Video quality</label></dt>
<dd id="video_quality-element">
<label for="video_quality-1"><input type="radio" name="video_quality" id="video_quality-1" value="1" class="input-radio">High (Minimum download bandwidth is 2 Mb/s)</label><br /><label for="video_quality-2"><input type="radio" name="video_quality" id="video_quality-2" value="2" checked="checked" class="input-radio">Low (Minimum download bandwidth is 0.5 Mb/s)</label></dd>
<dt id="save_settings-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="save_settings-element">
<input type="submit" name="save_settings" id="save_settings" value="Save" class="input-submit"></dd></dl></form>
```

Notice the

```
<br />
```

tag there. It should just be

```
<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's actually a bug, but you could override the default separator it uses, like so:

```
$video_quality = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('video_quality', array(
    'label' => 'Video quality',
    'required' => true,
    'separator' => '<br>', // here is the new separator
    'class' => 'input-radio',
    'multiOptions' => array(
        '1' => 'High (Minimum download bandwidth is 2 Mb/s)',
        '2' => 'Low (Minimum download bandwidth is 0.5 Mb/s)',
    )
));
```

or:

```
$video_quality->setSeparator( '<br>' );
```

Comment: Yes, but Zend_Form correctly uses HTML/XHTML tags in other cases (such as img tag for captcha) so it should also automatically detect whether to use br/ or just br to separate radio buttons as well. I hope they fix it in the next ZF release.

Comment: @Richard: I agree to an extent. The thing is though that it will be difficult to 'manage' so to speak, as the argument `$listsep` in the viewhelper `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio` is a simple string, which defaults to `<br />`. They'd have to assert whether the separator is meant as an (x)html tag to begin with, I guess. Because in theory you are allowed to pass any string as an argument.

Comment: @Richard: So it might not be a bug perse, but a choice of the designer to leave that responsibility up to the implementor.

Comment: Thanks. I am serving HTML/XHTML based on browser (HTML to <= IE8 and XHTML to IE9 and non IE browsers) and I want my code to be valid. I will just use a constant which stores user's browser to determine whether to set separator as br or br/.

Comment: But `HTML 4.01 strict` is essentially the same as `XHTML 1.1 strict`, unless you use specific `XML` features like namespaces. I prefer to use `HTML 4.01 strict` and am not aware of any differences in browser rendering between `XHTML strict` and `HTML strict`. But maybe I'm being ignorant here. :) To my knowlegde there's a big misunderstanding about XHTML being something way different than HTML. Admittedly, I haven't played with IE9 yet, so I'm assuming you know from experience. But I find it hard to imagine there are differences if you're just using the basic HTML compatible set of XHTML tags.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML also, to see what I'm after. Especially the paragraphs 'Adoption' and 'Criticism`.

Comment: I know about XHTML problems. But they were mainly caused by Internet Explorer which did not support serving XHTML as XML until version 9. I like to use XHTML because I still believe in the idea of semantic web and it might just get moving again now that all major browsers support serving XHTML as XML. And quite a lot of modern websites are already written in XHTML, it was just not possible to serve them correctly until now.

Comment: Well, maybe it's my own ignorance here again, but as far as I know the whole `XHTML` is better than `HTML` argument has always been a huge myth. Semantically `XHTML` is not any more meaningful than `HTML`. Provided you don't use `XML` features, `HTML strict` has the **exact** same tag-set as `XHTML strict`, but without the mandatory trailing `/>` for non-closing tags. And that's it! (To my knowledge that is :) ). No semantic difference what so ever.

Comment: (Unless search engines treat `XHTML` semantically different than `HTML`, which would indeed be pretty ignorant on my part, seeing I'm developing more than a decade now. If that **is** the case, let's hope my clients don't ever find out about my ignorance. :) )